# iOS convert a color to RGB

Tags: ios, uicolor

I have a function which receives a `UIColor` and needs to use it's RGBA values.
What I did so far was to use `CGColorGetComponents` but that doesn't work well for other colorspaces (for example `[UIColor blackColor]` which is in grayscale).
Using getRed green blue (in iOS 5) also doesn't work on `[UIColor blackColor]` (returns false).

Any easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method should work in most cases (except pattern-colors). Add it as a category to UIColor.

```
- (void)getRGBA:(CGFloat*)buffer {
        CGColorRef clr = [self CGColor];
        NSInteger n = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(clr);
        const CGFloat *colors = CGColorGetComponents(clr);
        switch (n) {
        case 2:
            for(int i = 0; i<3; ++i){
                buffer[i] = colors[0];
            }
            buffer[3] = CGColorGetAlpha(clr);
            break;
        case 3:
            for(int i = 0; i<3; ++i){
                buffer[i] = colors[i];
            }
            buffer[3] = 1.0;
            break;
        case 4:
            for(int i = 0; i<4; ++i){
                buffer[i] = colors[i];
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getRed:...` will return false if a color is not in the RGB color space. Pretty much the only other option is the grayscale color space, so if you try `getWhite:alpha:` you should get valid values back. The RGBA equivalent of this color will then have the white value for each of the R, G and B values.

Comment: There is a CMYK color space, but presumably Yaniv knows whether he's using it in his app.

Comment: @robmayoff - isn't CMYK NSColor only, UIColor doesn't support it.

Comment: Ha ha I should be more careful searching.  I was looking at `CGColorCreateGenericCMYK` which is indeed OS X only.